# Haskell Newbie - Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]

Tags: haskell

I am trying to make a function "tokenize" that takes 3 arguments; main String, String of chars that should be in their own String and a String of chars to remove from the string.

```
tokenize :: String -> String -> String -> [String]
tokenize [] imp remm = []
tokenize str imp remm =   let chr = (head str) in
                          if elem chr imp then ([chr] : (tokenize (tail str) imp remm))
                          else if (elem chr  remm ) then (tokenize (tail str) imp remm)
                          else chr: (tokenize (tail str) imp remm)
```

I get this error message :

```
Occurs check: 
cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
Expected type: [a]
Actual type: [[a]]
```

Comment: `[chr] : tokenize` is the culprit here, but that being said, this looks like way too complex.

Comment: Yea i figured. It's my first time trying functional programming so I am not that used to it yet. The problem is that if i remove the brackets I don't get elements of imp in their own list :/

Comment: What is the type of "tokenize" meant to be? If you give it a type definition you will often get a more helpful error message.

Comment: Oh, sorry I'll add that!

Comment: Its probably down to the fact that in one place you say `[chr]:tokenize` and later on you say `chr:tokenize`.

Comment: Yea, it works when i remove it or use ++ in place of :, but then I don't get the elements of imp in their own string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your expression, you use two subexpressions:

```
[chr] : (tokenize (tail str) imp remm))
```

and

```
chr: (tokenize (tail str) imp remm)
```

the two can not be in harmony with each other, since that would mean `[chr]` and `chr` have the same type hence the error.

Usually in functional programming the parameters are written in a different order. Indeed, it makes more sense to write it as `tokenize imp remm str` with `imp` the important characters, `remm` the characters to remove and `str` the string to process.

We can implement the fuction by using a helper function `go`. Here `go` basically should consider four cases:

1. we reached the end of the list, and thus return a singleton list with an empty list;
2. the first character is something to eliminate from the output, we recurse on the tail of the string;
3. the character is important, we yield an empty list, the character wrapped in a list, and recurse on the tail; and
4. if all above is not applicable, we prepend the character to the head of the list we retrieve when we recurse.

We filter out empty lists, that can occur when we have for example two consecutive characters that are in `imp`.

For example:

```
tokenize :: [Char] -> [Char] -> String -> [String]
tokenize imp remm = filter (not . null) . go
    where go [] = [[]]
          go (x:xs) | elem x remm = go xs
                    | elem x imp = [] : [x] : go xs
                    | otherwise = let (y:ys) = go xs in (x:y) : ys
```

We then yield:

```
Prelude> tokenize "abc" "def" "defaabyesays"
["a","a","b","ys","a","ys"]
```

It might however be better to solve separate problems by separte functions. For example first have a function that removes characters from `remm`, etc. This makes it more easy to understand and bugfix your function.